# ApiFetch pass variable from function JS

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I make an api call to an endpoing and inside the apiFetch I get a value. I want to display this value from outside the function but it doesn't get updated. Any ideas why it does this?

```
save: () => {
          var newValue="default";
          apiFetch( { path:'/url', } ).then( res => {
          newValue = (res[0].value);

          // this shows the new value
          console.log(newValue);

      } );
      //this shows "default"
      return <p>{newValue}</p>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is asynchronous, you can use `async`/`await`

```
save: async () => {
  const response = await apiFetch( { path:'/url', } );
  const newValue = response[0].value;
  console.log(newValue);
  return <p>{newValue}</p>
}
```

Then, inside your caller block:

```
const newValueParagraph = await yourobject.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to return your Promise. Right now you make the async request to the api, and while that's doing it's thing you return newValue which is still just 'default.

Try like this:

```
save: () => {
  var newValue = "default";
  return apiFetch({ path: '/url', }).then(res => {
    newValue = (res[0].value);

    // this shows the new value
    console.log(newValue);
    return <p>{newValue}</p>
  });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't return the <p> for some reason. It doesn't show any error but it doesn't display the html

Comment: Can you post the code where you use this save method